# assign id accordingly

Tags: django, google-app-engine, django-templates

```
{% for answer in AnswersQuery %}
    <div>
    <span>Choice:<input type=text name="answer" id="" value={{answer.answer}}>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"></span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

what above is a for loop in my django template. The goal is to display several input text field by the for loop,see the ID part, which I left it blank, is there way that I can assign id to each of the input during each cycle, like after the loop is done, I got 5 input fields with id ascending from 1 to 5. I know I can do it manually by typing 5 input field. would be that too trivial if I have a handred inputs. I have tried create a counter which is supposed to increase along with the loop repetition. like

```
{% for answer in AnswersQuery %}
    <div>
            i = 1
    <span>Choice:<input type=text name="answer" id="i" value={{answer.answer}}>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"></span>
            i++
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I know what I did is wrong, but I just want you to understand my idea. Dont you? any thought? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for

`{{ forloop.counter }}`

```
{% for answer in AnswersQuery %}
    <span>Choice:<input type=text name="answer" id="{{forloop.counter}}" value={{answer.answer}}>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"></span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also the default id for your purpose

```
{% for answer in AnswersQuery %}
    <span>Choice:<input type=text name="answer" id="{{answer.key.id}}" value={{answer.answer}}>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"></span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```